# Rouche's theorem to P(z)/Q(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Find that the number of roots of $$\frac{z^2-4}{z^2+4} + \frac{2z^4-1}{z^2+6} = 0$$ within the unit circle is zero.

So I have solved for $P(z) = (z^2-4)(z^2+6)$ and $Q(z) = (2z^4-1)(z^2+4)$.  I can't figure out how to prove that $|P(z)| \gt |Q(z)|$ so that I can apply the theorem.  I can solve for $|Q(z)| \le 13$ fairly easily, but I do not see how to prove that $|P(z)| \gt 13$.  I have been told that $|P(z)| \ge 21$, but do not see how to prove that.

Also, I am having trouble applying the theorem itself, assuming that the above checks out.  I need to show that $P(z)$ and $P(z)-Q(z)$ have the same number of roots in $C$.  The issue here is that solving for $|P(z)-Q(z)|$ yields $|-(z^4+5z^2+20)| \le 26.$  Even assuming that I can prove above that $|P(z)| \ge 21$, this still does not fulfill the theorem.

Am I applying the theorem incorrectly or is this problem not possible with Rouche's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need Rouché.

Try $P(z) = \dfrac{z^2-4}{z^2+4}$ and $Q(z) = \dfrac{2z^4-1}{z^2+6}$, which are both analytic in the unit disk.  Note that for $|z| \le 1$, $|P(z)| \ge \dfrac{3}{5}$ while $|Q(z)| \le \dfrac{3}{5}$.  Moreover, $|Q(z)| = 3/5$ would require   $z^2 = -1$, while $|P(z)| = 3/5$ would require $z^2 = 1$.

EDIT: If you want to do it your way, $|P(z)| = |z^2-4| |z^2 - 6|$ with (on the circle $|z|=1$) $|z^2-4| \ge 4 - 1 = 3$ and $|z^2-6| \ge 6-1 = 5$, so $|P(z)| \ge 15$.
Since, as you say, $|Q(z)| \le 13$ on the circle, Rouché says $P(z)$ and $P(z) + Q(z)$  have the same number of roots inside the circle.  But the roots of $P(z)$ are $\pm 2$ and $\pm \sqrt{6}$, which are outside the circle, so that number is $0$.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, the use of Rouché is specified in the problem.